# EditText with TextWatcher and Suggestions

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher

Moving an app from 2.2 to 3.x, one of my EditText's that I was using a `TextWatcher` on for validation is behaving badly. In short, when a user clicks on the `EditText` and the entire word goes into 'suggestions mode' (where it is underlined), it effectively gets removed from the EditText from the TextWatcher's perspective, triggering my text validation check that I do for an empty EditText. The code:

```
mText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inpt_title);
mText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        final String title = editable.toString();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "addTextChangedListener(): title: " + title + ", length: " + title.length());
    if (title.length() == 0) {
    // empty title
    mText.setError(getString(R.string.error_note_title_empty));
    }
}

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    mText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
}

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
});
```

I'd like to keep suggestions working, but there seems to be some weird interaction here.

Any way to either a) keep the EditText from being empty when the entire word is in 'suggestion mode', or at least checking to see if the EditText is in the 'suggestion' state to determine if the EditText is truly empty, or b) turing off suggestions? I've tried `android:inputType="text|textCapWords|textNoSuggestions"` for the EditText in question, as well as setting it via `mText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);` in the code above but suggestions keep happening on a Lenovo 3.1 tablet.

Update:

I see API 14 added a `isInputMethodTarget()` method to the EditText, which I could use to check for active suggestions and disable the validation... but I am running against API 12. Perhaps I could check the IME directly to see if the suggestions are active?

Comment: can you explain these suggestions? are you getting suggestions from your strings or are you talking about more about filtering text?